# VPN connection over squid

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, squid

If we setup proxy server with squid, would users be able to use VPN (over squid) to connect to remote servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the VPN. OpenVPN is a SSL VPN and [supports proxies](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http) as well as my Fortigate SSL VPN. I am not aware of other VPNs, but I think you may assume that SSL VPNs can be proxied.